# System Inputs - How to make my game object jump?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple platformer with a rolling ball that rolls around and collects coins to win each level. I'm using Unity's System input from Unity's package manager to help me with controls and key binding and have successfully gotten my ball to roll around with ease and collect coins with a nice UI setup. However, I would like to implement harder levels where the ball jumps. I can not figure out how to make the ball jump. I know there are others ways to go about this but I just can't figure out how to make it work in the system inputs.

(I know an if statement is needed to test if the ball is grounded however again I'm new and still learning)

[Gameplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f2z3.png) | [OnJump in player input is for jumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zSgk.png) | [KeyBindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2E75.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerController: MonoBehaviour

{
    public float speed = 0;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public float jumpForce;
    public TextMeshProUGUI countText;
    public GameObject winTextObject;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;
    private float movementX;
    private float movementY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        SetCountText();
        winTextObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        Vector2 movementVector = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();

        movementX = movementVector.x;
        movementY = movementVector.y;
    }
    private void onJump(InputValue value)
    {
        
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
        if(count >= 12)
        {
            winTextObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("PickUp")) 
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;

            SetCountText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a [`Unity Thread`](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1750687/implementing-jump-w-new-input-system.html) discussing how to jump using the new input system. Hopefully one of those two answers provides an answer. Along with detecting the input, you will also need to implement ground detection either using raycasts or collisions.

Comment: I appreciate both answers as they are both helpful my mentor told me both ways can be implemented i just really don't wanna change to the manual code (Input.GetKey etc) when the code I have currently is set up to work in junction with the system input that unity provides in its package manager. I'm gonna check out the link and keep working on it, thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a new tag called Ground and put it on everything you want your player to be able to jump on (the ground).

```
 public float jumpHeight = 5f;
 public bool isGrounded;  

 void Update()
 {
    if (isGrounded)//Checks if is on ground
    {
       if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))//If the space is pressed
       {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight)
       }
    }
 }
 
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)//If touch other object
 {
     if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")//If other object has Ground tag
     {
         isGrounded = true;
     }
 }
 
 void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
     {
         isGrounded = false;
     }
 }
```

You can also do `if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))` as

`if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))`

or

`if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))`

Comment: `if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))` is not using the same input system that is used in the question. This will not work for what the question is asking.